# XML Attribute not working in Node.js xml2js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xml2js

I'm trying to parse XML with Node.js and xml2js. In the documentation is says that $ is the character to access attributes. It doesn't seem to be working in my case.

The object result.ApiResponse.CommandResponse works fine. But anything I put afterwards is undefined.

Here's my code, it says $ is undefined :

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var util = require('util');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
var xml = '<ApiResponse Status="OK"><Errors/><Warnings/><RequestedCommand>namecheap.domains.check</RequestedCommand><CommandResponse Type="namecheap.domains.check"><DomainCheckResult Domain="us.xyz" Available="true" ErrorNo="0" Description="" IsPremiumName="true" PremiumRegistrationPrice="13000.0000" PremiumRenewalPrice="13000.0000" PremiumRestorePrice="65.0000" PremiumTransferPrice="13000.0000" IcannFee="0.0000" EapFee="0.0000"/></CommandResponse><Server>PHX01APIEXT01</Server><GMTTimeDifference>--5:00</GMTTimeDifference><ExecutionTime>4.516</ExecutionTime></ApiResponse>';

parser.parseString(xml, function (err, result) {

console.log(util.inspect(result.ApiResponse.CommandResponse.DomainCheckResult.$.Available, false, null))    

});
```

Here's the console.log(result):

```
{ ApiResponse: 
   { '$': { Status: 'OK' },
     Errors: [ '' ],
     Warnings: [ '' ],
     RequestedCommand: [ 'namecheap.domains.check' ],
     CommandResponse: 
      [ { '$': { Type: 'namecheap.domains.check' },
          DomainCheckResult: 
           [ { '$': 
                { Domain: 'us.xyz',
                  Available: 'true',
                  ErrorNo: '0',
                  Description: '',
                  IsPremiumName: 'true',
                  PremiumRegistrationPrice: '13000.0000',
                  PremiumRenewalPrice: '13000.0000',
                  PremiumRestorePrice: '65.0000',
                  PremiumTransferPrice: '13000.0000',
                  IcannFee: '0.0000',
                  EapFee: '0.0000' } } ] } ],
     Server: [ 'PHX01APIEXT01' ],
     GMTTimeDifference: [ '--5:00' ],
     ExecutionTime: [ '4.516' ] } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `CommandResponse` and `DomainCheckResult` are actually arrays, so you need to access their first elements using `[0]` before digging deeper into your data.

```
console.log(util.inspect(
    result.ApiResponse.CommandResponse[0].DomainCheckResult[0].$.Available,
    false, null
))
```